# admin block grid filter is reloading page issue in tab view

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

[image]

Need to avoid reloading entire page when searching field...

Comment: Use UI component instead of deprecated php grid class

Comment: Are u saying ui component listing??

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Actually am trying to list in edit page under tab view .. not index page

Comment: Am having two tabs and that one tab view has this grid